# Molecular dynamics (Mac OSX user): what software can I use to plot RDFs for NPT simulations? VMD only works for NVT (constant volume)

Tags: quantum-chemistry, atomic-structure, molecular-dynamics

I would be very grateful if someone could recommend a way to plot RDFs for NPT ensemble molecular dynamics simulation results.

I use CP2K to run NVT simulations and usually use VMD to process results, but I don't see a way in VMD to deal with NPT results, where the volume is different at each time step.  I'm hoping that someone can recommend a piece of software that can deal with my CP2K output (i.e., a position file in terms of atomic xyz coordinates and a file that contains volume output) on a Mac or Linux system.

I have spent several hours online looking for a solution, but haven't even come across discussions of this problem.  This seems odd so maybe I'm using the wrong search terms.  If anyone can point me to online discussions of this issue, that would be great.

I'm also not having much luck tagging this question!  If anyone knows of any molecular dynamics-related tags I could use to reach people or perhaps of a more appropriate StackExchange site, I would welcome any suggestions.  Thank you.

Comment: What happens if you attempt to use the existing processing tool to analyze the NPT data (pretending it's NVT)?

Comment: @Buck Thorn, thanks.  Let me know if my explanation isn't clear and I'll rewrite it.  VMD is set up to deal with NVT-type simulations where the volume is constant.  There's a GUI where a sinlge volume value can be entered.  So there's no way that I can see of importing my cell volume file and using a different volume value at each time step.  however, VMD has a sort of coding language and can be used via a terminal.  So I am wondering if there's a way to change the volume that way.  I have so far averaged my volumes for each simulation and have used those, but wonder if my RDFS are meaningful.

Comment: @Buck Thorn, there don't seem to be any other tags that would be appropriate.  "Molecular dynamics" and "ensemble" and related terms don't seem to be established as tags.

Comment: That's an important clarification. I'm guessing you mean this gui: http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/plugins/gofrgui/. The gui invokes the tcl command "measure gofr" with additional modifiers as described here: http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/current/ug/node138.html While somebody else might have the script you are looking for I can recommend familiarizing yourself with the tcl scripting language in vmd as not everything is "canned" and you may want to process using your homebrew macros.

Comment: I don't know how gofr works but you can try inspecting it. It probably sets the max r cutoff based on the box size (or volume I guess). In NPT the volume will vary but you may get away with using the smallest volume sampled in the ensemble from which rmax is computed, but that is just a guess.

Comment: I'll keep the tag because it's the only one I can see that relates to the problem.  people who are familiar with quantum chemistry may have run into the problem.

Comment: I see that CP2K is a QM sim package, but the question is about VMD. But ok, I see that the userbase extends beyond atomistic sims.

Comment: Thanks for those links. I'll go through them.  I have used the tcl scripting language before and am slowly getting up to speed, but it would be great if there were a straightforward way to do this without having to spend the time it would take to reach a level that would allow me to write my own code.  If anyone out there knows of an easier way, that would be great.

Comment: What are your thoughts on using an average volume (computed from the volumes at each time step) in the existing GUI VMD method for calculating RDFs?

Comment: I'm not sure. My intuition tells me using a lower bound is safer but I'd look for the script gofr first. Depends also how much the volume is varying. For an incompressible substance it might not make a difference.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion on that, Buck Thorn.  I will look for a script, but so far have had no luck!  I am just about ready to submit a paper where I've used an average volume for my RDFs, but suddenly started feeling uncomfortable.  I'm not a mathematician and appreciate any opinions anyone has.  Appreciate your time.

Comment: The volume is probably only used to select a cutoff. If the cutoff is greater than the box size than presumably it has to apply pbcs. I also haven't found the script, I think it's actually a compiled subroutine.

Comment: I could very well be talking nonsense because this sort of thing goes beyond my expertise, but my concern is that the volume is used to determine how far apart atoms in the box are from each other.  So therefore, if using an average volume is somehow a problem (if it is squishing atoms too close together or making them be too far apart from each other), I might be calculating bond lengths that are incorrect.  That will mean that I won't correctly identify stable complexes in my system.  Anyway, I will keep searching and considering your comments.  Thanks.

Comment: My guess is it assumes the same units across ensemble snapshots and doesn't rescale, but again it's a guess. If I'm wrong then you do have something to worry about.

Comment: I recommend testing on a NVT sim result using two different volumes and other gofr parameters to see if they make a difference.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to think about what you said.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, Buck, for all your suggestions.  You're right that a good way to check the influence of the volume is to try varying it.  I did that by using the maximum and minimum volumes of the fluctuations in one simulation.  There was some variation, so the volume does matter!

I was lucky enough to hear about "travis," an amazingly simple-to-compile code (even for Macs) available online for free.  I thought I'd share that information here because other people are bound to run into this same problem.  This code, travis, takes my trajectory file and my volume file and then asks a number of questions interactively.  It outputs a nice CSV file that can be plotted.

Thanks again for your help, Buck.  Really helped me think this through.  I'd like to ask the moderators or whoever is in charge of tagging to please add some molecular dynamics-related tags if possible!  Thank you.

Comment: It's cool that you found this software, that looks very useful for dissecting your simulations. I would be careful interpreting the effect of altering the volume setting in the gofr gui. I found the associated c routines which it presumably calls, you'll find them in the VMD source code (Measure.C).

Comment: regarding "molecular dynamics" tags, I took the freedom to add one to your question yesterday.

Comment: Reading the help page for "measure", at http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Research/vmd/current/ug/node138.html, it says: "The size of the unitcell has to be stored in the trajectory file or has to be set manually for all frames with the molinfo command. The command uses by default only the current active frame for both selections." Not sure how this impacts your analysis. I take back a previous comment regarding pbcs etc as "usepbc=0" looks to be the default. I have to say again that you may get more mileage from posting a question at the vmd users forum.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Buck!  That's good advice.  I wasn't aware that  there are VMD C code routines.  They'll be easier for me to understand than the VMD tcl script.

Comment: Thank you also for adding the MD tags!  I think your comment above means that in future, I need to set something in CP2K before running it that includes the effects of a varying unit call in my trajectory output.  I think I know how to do this now.  Unfortunately, I have many simulations that I can't redo, so I'm over the moon to know about travis.  I was very worried I would not be able to use my existing simulations.  Anyway, thank you so much for your help.  Really calmed me down and put me on the right track.